# Detecting an OS batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, operating-system

I need a batch script that can display witch windows OS it is running because I am making a program and what it does is greatly affected by witch OS it is running. The ones I need it to test for are:

```
Windows 8 32bit
Windows 8 64bit
Windows 7 32bit
Windows 7 64bit
Windows vista 32bit
Windows vista 64bit
Windows xp
Other
```

Does anyone know what I could do as I don’t know where to start?

Comment: Some other answers to similar questions have used wmic.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042339/os-name-variable

Comment: why use a batch file?  what lanugage are you writing your program in?  If you're using .NET, you can detect the version from the code

Comment: I am using batch to make the full program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type the following command in a cmd prompt

```
ver
```

this will list the microsoft windows version. You'll just have to map each version to your functionality accordingly.

If you need more detail than this, the systeminfo command outputs a bunch of info.

You'll likely want to filter it. For example to get the version + service pack info + processor architecture:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"System Type"
```

outputs the following on my machine:

```
 OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

Comment: It works but it says "Microsoft Windows [6.1.7601]" it doesn’t actually say windows 7 32bit or windows 8 64bit or something the batch file can easily read.

Comment: see edits. type in systeminfo. you can filter whichever results you'd like by adding additional /C:"Attribute Name" parameters to findstr

Comment: Do you know any other commands like the "/C:"System Type"" bit because this could also be used as a debug section so it will tell me what sort of computer it is runing on. CPU speed and RAM would be good. Thanks

Comment: just type systeminfo. This will print out all the available fields it provides. You can then add the /C: for whichever you want to filter out

Answer (score 3):

Copied from ["Determining OS version via Scripting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302466/determining-os-version-via-scripting/16305107#16305107):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Identify OS
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do set ver=%%a
set Version=
for %%a in (95=95 98=98 ME=ME NT=NT 2000=2000 5.1.=XP 5.2.=2003 6.0.=Vista 6.1.=7 6.2.=8) do (
   if "!Version!" equ "this" (
      set Version=Windows %%a
   ) else if "!ver: %%a=!" neq "%ver%" (
      set Version=this
   )
)

::Identify bit
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)" (
   set Type=64 bit
) else (
   set Type=32 bit
)

::Display result
echo %Version% %Type%
echo/
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ver` command, then filter using "|"

example

```
ver|find "6.1" >nul && echo/Windows XP
```

Answer (score 2):

Detect Windows Version, create a variable **OS_VERSION**:

```
@echo off
@break off
@title Detect Windows Version - Create Variable = OS_VERSION
@color 0a
@cls

ver | findstr /i "5\.0\.">nul
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 set "OS_VERSION=2000"

ver | findstr /i "5\.1\.">nul
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 set "OS_VERSION=XP"

ver | findstr /i "5\.2\.">nul
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 set "OS_VERSION=2003"

ver | findstr /i "6\.0\.">nul
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 set "OS_VERSION=Vista"

ver | findstr /i "6\.1\.">nul
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 set "OS_VERSION=7"

ver | findstr /i "6\.2\.">nul
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 set "OS_VERSION=8"

echo %OS_VERSION%
pause
exit
```

Detect Windows BITS, create a variable **OS_BITS**:

```
@echo off
@break off
@title Detect Windows BITS - Create Variable = OS_BITS
@color 0a
@cls

if "%ProgramW6432%" EQU "%ProgramFiles%" if "%CommonProgramW6432%" EQU "%CommonProgramFiles%" if defined ProgramFiles(x86) if exist "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\" (
  set "OS_BITS=64"
) else (
  set "OS_BITS=32"
)

echo %OS_BITS%
pause
exit
```

PS: Tested in Windows XP x86, Windows 7 x86, Windows 7 x64, Windows 8 x64, Windows 2008 x64

Answer (score 1):

WMIC is better method compared to ver as it includes the architecture requirement.

```
wmic os get caption, OSArchitecture, version
```

Result

```
Caption                       OSArchitecture  Version
Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate  64-bit          6.1.7600
```

EDIT: I see 75inch has updated his systeminfo command while I was posting mine.  Either way will work.